# Secondary schools Ireland, UK & Finland

Tags: data-request, education, uk, ireland

Does someone know where to find the contact information of all the secondary schools of Ireland, Finland and UK? I am researching for schoolnames, place, e-mail and post adress. I found already some schools, but I am still missing a lot of schools.

So far I have found these lists: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_schools_in_Northern_Ireland
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_schools_in_Finland